# how can I print 2 copies at once C#

Tags: c#

This code below is printing a copy of a 'PDF' file and I'm having trouble making it to print 2 copies of it, not just one can anyone help?

```
string Filepath = path+ @"\Output.pdf";
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
{
    CreateNoWindow = true,
    Verb = "print",
    FileName = Filepath //put the correct path here
 };
 p.Start();
 p.Start();
```

Comment: Try using `WaitForExit` or `WaitForExitAsync` before calling `Start` a second time.

Comment: Deleted my comment, as @juharr's is better

Comment: @juharr when I call p.Start twice it won't do anything, adding wait for exit will it help? or is there a way to make it print 2 copies by default.

Comment: I'm guessing the second call you make sees that the process is already started and doesn't actually do anything.  It might also work if you create a second instance of the `Process` and start it, but I'm not 100% sure.